# Pymel: finding UV coordinates for specified face

Tags: python, coordinates, maya, uv-mapping, pymel

In pymel what would be the best way to find the Uv coordinates of a specified face (in this case the face is a quad and has its UVs are layed out just for that face so it is only connected to 4 UVs)

Thanks

Comment: Do you have to use pymel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want to use

```
cmds.polyEvaluate(uvComponent=true)
```

The polyEvaluate command lets you get a bunch of different information about polygons in maya.

https://help.autodesk.com/cloudhelp/2016/CHS/Maya-Tech-Docs/CommandsPython/polyEvaluate.html

Comment: but uvComponent doesn't return UV coordinates for specified face, it "returns the object's number of selected uv coordinates as an int ". I don't see the question get answered?